# Нужна ли запятая у наречного выражения?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, сложное-предложение

"Тебе мать просто звонила, и в итоге мне написала"
Нужна ли поставленная запятая? Становится ли из-за "в итоге" предложение сложным, или в нём однородные сказуемые, разделённые союзом "и"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

***Тебе мать просто звонила и в итоге мне написала.***

Можно и без запятой написать, пусть это будут однородные сказуемые, соединительный союз И. Считать такое предложение сложным нет оснований, здесь одна предикативная основа: *мать звонила и написала.*

Но интонация **бесцветная, невыразительная, скучная.** И анализ такой же, хотя и правильный, то есть чисто умозрительный, равнодушный.  А ведь это разговорная речь, ее можно по-разному оформить

Лучше использовать присоединительную конструкцию:
***Тебе мАть просто звонила, //  и в итоге мнЕ написала.***

Это тоже простое предложение, но между сказуемыми присоединительные отношения, и союз И в этом случае тоже присоединительный. Здесь ведь не просто так выбран подходящий для обособления **порядок слов**.

Сравнить: ***Тебе мать просто звонила и  написала мне в итоге.*** Такое предложение удобнее прочитать без паузы.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу поддержку.

Comment: Тоже хотел ответить на этот вопрос, особенно после первого ответа. Тоже собирался отметить явно разговорный характер, а за неимением контекста – вариативность смысловых оттенков. Мне кажется, что этот случай очень схож с недавним обсуждением простоты/сложности предложения, где есть союз И. Может, и его можно рассматривать как сложное с подразумеваемым подлежащим "она" во второй части? А можно вообще тире поставить, увидев здесь причинно-следственную связь: мать звонила тебе (не дозвонилась), поэтому мне написала в итоге. В любом случае присоединение выглядит предпочтительней.

Comment: Да,  не могу с вами не согласиться. Кроме того, вы отметили те МОМЕНТЫ, которые я не рассматриваю, но они тоже впечатляют. Речевой вариант со сложным предложением и  местоимением  вполне возможен как реальный вариант. Тире действительно подчеркнет причинно-следственный характер отношений.  Все это наводит на мысль о том, что в разговорной речи отношения скорее не присоединительные (с добавочным характером), а РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ с разными ОТТЕНКАМИ значений.

Comment: Мы как бы последовательно развиваем  нашу мысль и в каждом следующем сообщении даем новую информацию, в том числе и с оттенком обоснования ранее сказанного. Все это при обобщенной оценке имеет характер РАЗНЫХ СИТУАЦИЙ, а это тема сложных предложений. Вот поэтому и делаем мы здесь паузу (и ставим запятую), чтобы ПЕРЕЙТИ от одной ситуации к другой.  Приведенное предложение, которое  мы по грамматике считаем простым, в действительности имеет интонацию сложного предложения.

Comment: Я   просто отвечала очень быстро, на эмоциях – мгновенная реакция, грамматический разбор меня «вдохновил». Зря вы не дали еще один ответ,  ваша точка зрения заслуживает ОТДЕЛЬНОГО ВНИМАНИЯ. Я бы за вас обязательно проголосовала  (Шэрон учится, спасибо).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если есть одно подлежащее, к которому относятся разные действия, то все эти действия считаются однородными сказуемыми. В предложении: «Я вышел из дома, пошел в лес, нарубил дров, принес их домой, затопил печь» — «вышел», «пошел», «нарубил», «принес», «затопил» — все это однородные сказуемые.
При «в итоге» таже пунктуация, что и при любом обстоятельстве времени, вроде «после всего».
Вот ссылка на справочник по всяким сложным случаям, которая подтверждает вышесказанное:
http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=278#pp278
В итоге получается следующая пунктуация: «Тебе мать просто звонила и в итоге мне написала».